# JQuery scroller error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this example of a page scroller which also sets the navigation as active on scroll.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/m2zQE/)

Hope you can help.

In the console I see this error.

> TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined [Break On This Error]
>
> contentTop.push( $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top );

HTML

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#1">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#4">D</a></li>
        <li><a href="#5">E</a></li>
        <li><a href="#6">F</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

JS

```
smoothScroll: function() {
     var topRange      = 200,  // measure from the top of the viewport to X pixels down
         edgeMargin    = 20,   // margin above the top or margin from the end of the page
         animationTime = 1200, // time in milliseconds
         contentTop = [];

     // Stop animated scroll if the user does something
     $('html,body').bind('scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup', function(e){
     if ( e.which > 0 || e.type == 'mousedown' || e.type == 'mousewheel' ){
      $('html,body').stop();
     }
    })

     // Set up content an array of locations
     $('#nav').find('a').each(function(){
      contentTop.push( $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top );
     })

     // Animate menu scroll to content
      $('#nav').find('a').click(function(){
       var sel = this,
           newTop = Math.min( contentTop[ $('#nav a').index( $(this) ) ], $(document).height() - $(window).height() ); // get content top or top position if at the document bottom
       $('html,body').stop().animate({ 'scrollTop' : newTop }, animationTime, function(){
        window.location.hash = $(sel).attr('href');
       });
       return false;
     })

     // adjust side menu
     $(window).scroll(function(){
      var winTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
          bodyHt = $(document).height(),
          vpHt = $(window).height() + edgeMargin;  // viewport height + margin
      $.each( contentTop, function(i,loc){
       if ( ( loc > winTop - edgeMargin && ( loc < winTop + topRange || ( winTop + vpHt ) >= bodyHt ) ) ){
        $('#nav li a')
         .removeClass('selected')
         .eq(i).addClass('selected');
       }
      })
     })
  },
```

Comment: what browser is the error happening on? Fiddle runs fine on FF and Chrome. Error basically is saying it could not fine the element and offset returned undefined which has no top.

Comment: simpler way to get the hash is `contentTop.push( $( this.hash ).offset().top );`

Comment: Yes, the example works fine; that's the example i'm copying, but when I add the script into my own project I see the error above.